# How to play a transparent background video of .flv / .mp4 format in iOS application?

Tags: ios, iphone, transparency, mp4, flv

How to play a transparent background video of .flv / .mp4 format in iOS application?

I am getting black background instead of transparent background when I play the video using MPMoviePlayerController.

Any idea how to play with transparent background?

```
            MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
            player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
            player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
            player.view.frame = videoImageView.frame;
            player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
            for(UIView* subV in player.view.subviews) {
                subV.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            }
            for(UIView* subV in player.backgroundView.subviews) {
                subV.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            }
            player.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            player.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            player.view.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            player.backgroundView.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            player.view.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor]CGColor];
            player.backgroundView.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor]CGColor];
```

I had also Used AVPlayer and it is also showing black background

```
        avAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Video_Thumb_01" ofType:@"mp4"]]];
        avPlayerItem =[[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:avAsset];
        avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];
        avPlayerLayer =[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
        [avPlayerLayer setFrame:videoImageView.frame];
        [avPlayerLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor]CGColor]];
        [avPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
        [avPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayerController is displayed in it's own context. If you want to add a video to a UIViewcontroller (and I guess that's what you want as you want to deisplay something below the video), you should use [AVPLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html) to play the Video and use AVPlayerLayer to add the Video to your View.

Comment: I had also Used AVPlayer and it is also showing black background, see updated question

Comment: Maybe this Tutorial can help you: http://emilytoop.com/2012/05/16/playing-movies-with-an-alpha-channel-on-the-ipad/

Comment: ./qtexportani <name>.mov

is not creating any file export_<name>.mov